# Java заменить звездочками

Tags: java, строки

Есть строка, нужно заменить звездочками * все кроме последних 3-х символов.
Помогите разобраться на примере.

Comment: В чём разобраться? Вы что-то пытались сделать?

Comment: Сделать новую строку в которой нужное количество звездочек и в конце три последних символа исходной строки. Читайте описание строковых функций вашего языка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элементарно же:

```
String text = "123456789"; // исходный текст
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile( ".(?!.{,2}$)", Pattern.DOTALL ); // создаем регулярное выражение, которое совпадает с любым литералом, кроме трёх последних в тексте
text = regex.matcher( text ).replaceAll( "*" ); // заменяем на звездочки
```

Comment: а квантификатор `?!` тут разве нужен? ведь есть якорь — `$`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, это негативная позиционная проверка, она чтобы не матчило литерал, если справа от 0 до 3 литералов и конец текста.

Comment: хохо представляю рожу студента, который пытается объяснить преподу "как это работает"

Comment: @arg ну я же прокомментировал все строки специально.

Comment: Товарищ ТС, я пошутил. Надо просто сделать строку из звездочек с длиной на 3 меньше исходного текста и в конец добавить 3 последние символы текста. Все делается с помощью базовых операций.